# Get an item from another array with the same index in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The situation is: I have two tables with the same amount of rows and columns (for this explanation i will call them **table1** and **table2**).

Basically I have to show the values from **table1** beside the value from the same row and column in **table2**. eg:

**table1**:

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

**table2**:

```
5 [1: this value comes from the same row and column from table1] | 6 [2]
7 [3] | 8[4]
```

Now, I have a matrix (an array, with arrays) with the following structure in *knockout*:

```
var vm = header([{ 
    lots: [1, 2], 
    otherLots: [3, 4] 
}, { 
    lots: [5, 6], 
    otherLots: [7, 8] 
}]);
```

And then I apply this model to some bindings as you see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vece/).

The problem, is that `$parent.lots[$index].count` doesn't return anything as I expected.
I also tried with `ko.computed` and it didn't work.

Also this values are `ko.observable` so when I modify it in **table1**, this change should be reflected in **table2**

Is there a workaround for this requirement to work?

Comment: Keep in mind that `$index` is an observable, so you need to use it like `$index()` to get the value.   Likewise, `lots` is an observableArray, so you would need to call `$parent.lots()` to access the underlying array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you simply aren't calling the underlying observables. See my fork of your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cellenburg/kWh2V/1/

```
<p data-bind="text: $parent.lots()[$index()] ? $parent.lots()[$index()].count : ('nothing to show at index ' + $index())"  />
```

I changed the previous line to call the observable `$index()` and `lots()`.

Hope this helps.